# federated SPARQL - return information from two data sets

Tags: sparql, jena, federated-queries

I would like to return all the information from both data sets, without merging them, just plain return everything that matches in either of them, without being concerned if this data exists in another data base.

So far the closest I am is this:

```
PREFIX table: <https://data.nasa.gov/ontologies/atmonto/NAS#>
select ?name ?icao ?iata ?name2 ?icao2 ?iata2
where {

  SERVICE <http://localhost:3030/nasa/query> 
  {
      ?subject  table:icaoAirportCode   ?icao .
      ?subject  table:iataAirportCode   ?iata .
      ?subject  table:airportName   ?name .
  }

SERVICE <http://localhost:3030/newOurDb/query> 
{
    ?airport    table:icaoAirportCode   ?icao2 .
      ?airport  table:iataAirportCode   ?iata2 .
      ?airport  table:airportName   ?name2 .
}
}
```

but this requires copying columns. Can I ask both databases and still have just 3 columns?

Comment: Have tou tried `UNION`?